# Регулярные выражения, работа с jsoup

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, jsoup

Доброго времени суток. Помогите кто знает составить правильное выражение, вообще не могу в них разобраться.

Работаю с `jsoup`, через неё получаю html-код одного из искомых блоков:

```
<!--Ad Injection:top--> 
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
 <center>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script> 
  <!-- MySite.ru Adaptive 1 --> 
  <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-6747406633235216" data-ad-slot="7606784485" data-ad-format="auto"></ins> 
  <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
 </center>
</div>
<div>
 Моя подруга пообещала подарить своей дочке новый iPad за то, что она перейдет из шестого класса в седьмой.
</div> 
<div>
 Мне в детстве родители обещали дать по шее, если не перейду!
</div> 
<div class="addtoany_share_save_container addtoany_content_bottom">
 <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 addtoany_list a2a_target" id="wpa2a_1">
  <a class="a2a_button_facebook" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/facebook?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.ru%2Farchives%2F45450&amp;linkname=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82" title="Facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  <a class="a2a_button_twitter" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/twitter?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.ru%2Farchives%2F45450&amp;linkname=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82" title="Twitter" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  <a class="a2a_button_vk" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/vk?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.ru%2Farchives%2F45450&amp;linkname=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82" title="VK" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  <a class="a2a_button_odnoklassniki" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/odnoklassniki?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.ru%2Farchives%2F45450&amp;linkname=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82" title="Odnoklassniki" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  <a class="a2a_button_google_plus" href="http://www.addtoany.com/add_to/google_plus?linkurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.ru%2Farchives%2F45450&amp;linkname=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82" title="Google+" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  <a class="a2a_dd addtoany_share_save" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a> 
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
if(wpa2a)wpa2a.script_load();
//--></script> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Применяю метод `replaceAll` для переноса строк и метод с регуляркой, которую нашел на просторах интернета (в данном примере `<br>` нет, но есть на других страницах парсеного сайта:

`.replaceAll("<br>", "\n").replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>", "")`

Получаю в итоге такое:

```
// граница







(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});




 Моя подруга пообещала подарить своей дочке новый iPad за то, что она перейдет из шестого класса в седьмой.


 Мне в детстве родители обещали дать по шее, если не перейду!












// граница
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подправить регулярку, чтобы привести текст к толковому виду: убрать пустые строки-пробелы, в примере не видно, но каждая пустая строка содержит несколько пробелов, видимо в зависимости сколько на ней тегов было и прикрутить к ней очистку `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

Требуется вытянуть текст:

```
Моя подруга пообещала подарить своей дочке новый iPad за то, что она перейдет из шестого класса в седьмой.
Мне в детстве родители обещали дать по шее, если не перейду!
```

Comment: А какой текст из приведенного блока Вы хотите получить?

Comment: @post_zeew, обновил пост.

Comment: Удалить пустые строки, можно, например, так `String.replaceAll("\\s*?\\r?\\n\\s*?(?=\\r\\n|\\n)", "")`.

Comment: @post_zeew, подскажите пожалуйста, а как можно удалить `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`? Может как-то можно составить регулярку для удаления всего между указанными блоками, например как здесь: между `(` и `);`?

Comment: А зачем это удалять, если это можно не добавлять? Воспользуйтесь возможностями `jSoup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть `String page` – Ваш блок. Тогда:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page);
Element firstTextElement = doc.select("div").get(1);
Element secondTextElement = doc.select("div").get(2);
String text = (firstTextElement.html() + "\n" + secondTextElement.html()).replace("<br>", "");
```

В итоге, в `text` будет искомый текст, в которым теги `<br>` будут заменены на переносы строк.

`"<br>"` можете заменить на `" <br>"` или на `"<br> "`, смотря как в тексте этот тег расположен.

Comment: Я раньше так и использовал, сейчас код немного поменялся, приходится подстраиваться. Тогда спрошу про `Jsoup`: имеется вот [такая](http://i82.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1014/19/fa617fbf62b2d9f2cc597bacfb5ee119.png) структура одного поста. Я её тяну через `doc.select("div[class=inside-article] div[class=entry-content] div");`. На выходе получаю такой вот не совсем последовательный [список](http://i78.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1014/75/f45b4dee2665f0b24211457a69bc6975.png). Если бы искомая была каждая третья строка, то нет проблем, а тут вначале списка непорядок и не катит такое.

Comment: Так вот вопрос: можно ли жестко задать условие на `.select`, чтобы парсить голый `div`, как в этой ситуации (скрин второй), т.е. если в `div` есть что-то типа `style="margin-bottom:10px;"`, то исключать эту позицию?

Comment: Можно. Например, так: `div:not([style]):not([class])`.

Comment: Кстати, если вдруг не знаете, есть [вот такая](https://try.jsoup.org/) полезная штука.

Comment: За "штуку" спасибо, не знал о такой) Про `div:not` теперь буду знать, очень полезная вещь, решает множество задач) Спасибо большое)

Comment: Тут всплыл еще один момент: `doc.select("div[class=inside-article] div[class=entry-content] div:not([style]):not([class])");`, вот данный селект парсит пустые `div`, а можно ли сюда добавить, что ему надо парсить еще и пустой тег `p`? Простое добавление в конец `p` выдает пустой результат.

Comment: Тут стоит оговориться, что данное выражение выбирает пустые `div` только в *данном конкретном случае*, так как тут только три типа `div`, два из которых он убирает из результата. В *общем случае* (при наличии других `div`) будут убираться только те, которые есть в конструкции `not`.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на страницу и скажите, что нужно спарсить.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня просто получается что где-то текст в `div`, а где-то в `p`. Я тогда просто по условию сделаю парсинг `p`, если `div` пуст.